# JavaScript Parsing Date in Format of Dec/31st/2019

Tags: javascript

I have an irregular date format that I would like to parse into a new Date() in JavaScript. Does anyone know the preferred method of parsing dates in this format: Dec/31st/2019

Comment: Have you looked at the moment.js library? http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - if you tell it the format it'll parse it correctly. For example to get a date like `2019-12-31`, you would do the following:

```
var d = 'Dec/31st/2019';
console.log(moment(d, 'MMM/DDst/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')) // 2019-12-31
```